# Codename One iOS build error: Implicit declaration of function 'java_lang_NullPointerException___INIT___' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, xcode, codenameone

I'm trying to build the iOS source code generated by the CodeName One build server. I specifically upgraded to the Basic account to have this feature.

I'm experiencing build errors on XCode 5.1.1 which are similar to this one:

```
/build/xcode/src/app/java_lang_NoSuchFieldError.m:227:5: Implicit
declaration of function 'java_lang_NullPointerException___INIT___' is invalid in C99
```

This is what I did:

1. Take a functioning CodenameOne app (mine didn't work so I also tried with KitchenSink with similar results)
2. I followed the steps from the guide in the [how-do-i section](http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html)

   - load the xcode project from dist
   - added everything from res
   - added selectively from btres: *.xib, *.a, *.res, *.strings
3. Additionally I had to change the architecture in: build settings / architectures / standard architectures

After that I hit the error above. The obvious solution is to declare functions before use, per the restrictions of the C99 language standard, but after including the required headers a few times I gave up.

The way I see it, this could happen because something else needs to be adjusted in the xcode project (I'm not too familiar with iOS development). Also it could be a code generation bug.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use xcode 5.0 and not 5.1 which only works with the new VM. You can download older versions from Apples developer site.